# Gridview Header dropdown list filtering not firing SelectedIndexChanged method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've dropdownlist in the each column header of the gridview that is populated dynamically in gridview_rowdatabound event. It is placed for the filtering functionality.

I'm able to get the drop down and list of items but the select index changed method is not getting fired

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //some condition

    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    //some ddl properties
    ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

I've also place a new event handler method  but this event is not getting fired.

```
private void ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = "reached on select Index changed";
}
```

Any suggestion on how to get the upto this method on ddl change event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the `SelectedIndexChanged` event inside the `RowDataBound` event.

Because it is called only on page load, and not on PostBack (if you wrapped the databinding inside `if (!IsPostBack) { }` that is), the binding is lost on PostBack and the method will not be executed.

So you have to make sure you add the handler on every page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = mySource;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    DropDownList ddl = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
    ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged);
}
```